# How to arrange multiple rasters in columns

Tags: r, stack, raster, tiff

I'm trying to import 3 rasters into R using

```
library(raster)
mytif <- list.files(path=my path, pattern =".tif$", recursive=T, full.names=TRUE)
s <- stack(mytif)
```

but it shows  are 3 grids arranged horizontally and I want to arrange them vertically
R shows my raster with 2025 rows and 3 columns, my desired result is 2025*3 rows and 1 columns!

I am new to R, I would like to know more about how to work with rasters

Comment: can you include the output from `show(s)` (as text, do not include screenshots)?  I assume you have 3 *layers*?  For tutorials, see https://rspatial.org/

Comment: thanks for the tutorial i checked it out